# Need help to find a bit wise operation to fit my case study

Tags: bit-manipulation

I want to do bit operation between operand A and operand B so that result has the following bits.

Note: 1 = set , 0 = clear so

```
    A =      1010
    B =      0011
    Result=  0011
```

That is, I want to inverse A bit if A and B are different, keep A bit if A and B are the same.

Some more examples:

```
    Original=Set  |Clear|Set|Clear
    Latest  =Clear|Clear|Set|Set
    Result  =Clear|Clear|Set|Set

    A=0001
    B=1000
    Result=1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to retain B in all cases. As your truth table shows. You go through all possibilities, and for all of them you get B back....